# App actions doesn't work with google assistant for Internal testing version

Tags: android, react-native, app-actions, google-assistant

I developed an application with react-native and I add app actions to the application.

I followed instructions on docs and test the app by App Action Test Tools (AATT) and it worked pretty well (the invocation name is 'Test app').

After creating the preview for actions, I tried with google voice assistant directly (not just using AATT) and still it worked pretty well.

Right now I create a project in google play console with name 'MyApp' and create an Internal testing release and add another user as a tester and upload aab file for this release.

Finally I shared the google play link with tester user.
Tester user installed the app but actions doesn't work with google voice assistant!! I tried different commands, such as 'Hey google, search time in My App' and 'Hey google, search time in Test App' and etc. But non of them worked!

Do I need 'create preview' for Internal testing?

This step is not clear to me, what I need to do more to be sure the app will work with voice assistant without create preview by AATT?

Comment: The test tool preview is used only for testing during development for the user that's signed in to Android Studio.  The actual users of the APK downloaded from the Play store should be able to use voice actions declared in actions.xml for that APK.

Comment: Yes, Exactly, But the test user or actual user can't use voice actions, I mean they don't work for test users!

Comment: There's not enough information here to know what the problem is.  Your question should outline the full set of steps taken that reproduces the problem, so that anyone can do the same and observe for themselves.

Comment: The problem is, if I try to bring all steps here, it's a lot as you know. So I tried to explain briefly what I have done so far.
1) test with AATT and works well

2) test directly with google voice assistant, works well.
3) create a project in google play console and filled necessary information
4) create signed aab file by android studio and upload it in console to share with test user in Internal testing
5) add some users to test.
6) share the link to download from google play with them.
7)test user installed the app. the app works fine but google voice assistant does not work.

Comment: Right, unfortunately, without the ability to reproduce the issue, there's not much we can do.  The product is not fundamentally broken, so something is wrong somewhere in the process.  And that can't really be narrowed down without full repro steps.  We can't eliminate the possibility that you might be doing something wrong, nor can we eliminate some specific problem with the product.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson for your time.

Comment: I am also getting this issue. Any luck @Shab63 ?

Comment: In my case, @dewijones92, I upload my release version on google play console around  a month ago, but to review app actions it took much time to review for the google team. I received yesterday the response from google team. according support team, if the app-actions-review team approve your app actions then it will work fine.

Comment: @Shab63 just to clarify it took a month for your actions to be approved?

Comment: Yes, but they usually respond faster, probably in this time it takes to much time to response. But they didn't approve mine they mentioned a problem in my app actions.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I got the same issue. My testing app only works with ADB intent, but it is not recognized by voice. If I understood correctly, I need to push the App into production and let Google review my App Actions in order to be able to use my voice or even tell Google "Hey Google open my TestApp" ?